# containsLocation cooperation with loop & common fields

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to count common field of 2 polygons using *containsLocation* option to make huge amount of the same small fields placed only in common field. I think something is wrong with  *containsLocation(**this**, pole1)*. I tried many other ways, still not working. If you have got an idea how to count complex polygons common field you might write it down here also.

**Problem**

```
var x,y,countmarkers;countmarkers=0;
for(x=52.8;x<=54;x=x+0.15){
    for(y=12.6;y<=19;y=y+0.25) {

        var point = { lat: x, lng: y};
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, pole1)) {
             if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, pole2)){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
                     map: map
                 });
                 countmarkers++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Full code**

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      center: {lat: 52.597060, lng: 18.516048},
      zoom: 6
  };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    var pole0;
    pole0 = [
        [
         new google.maps.LatLng(54, 14),
         new google.maps.LatLng(53, 14),
         new google.maps.LatLng(53, 15),
         new google.maps.LatLng(54, 15)],
        [
            new google.maps.LatLng(54, 15),
            new google.maps.LatLng(53, 13),
            new google.maps.LatLng(53, 17),
            new google.maps.LatLng(54, 17)]
    ];
    var pole2,pole1;
    pole1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        //map: map,
        paths: pole0[0],
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeWeight: 4,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    });
    pole2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        //map: map,
        paths: pole0[1],
        strokeColor: '#ffffff',
        strokeWeight: 4,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    });


var x,y,countmarkers;countmarkers=0;
for(x=52.8;x<=54;x=x+0.15){
    for(y=12.6;y<=19;y=y+0.25) {

        var point = { lat: x, lng: y};
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, pole1)) {
             if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, pole2)){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
                     map: map
                 });
                 countmarkers++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

//if you comment "problem" part of code & "map: map" in polygon declarations, 
//this listener will work well, placing markers only in polygon "pole1"
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, pole1)) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: e.latLng,
                map: map
            });
        }

    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: `Point` should be  a `google.maps.LatLng` instance not `{lat: x, lng: y}`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Still doesn't works.

Comment: Did you tried `if (pole1.containsLatLng(point) && pole2.containsLatLng(point) {... ` ?

Comment: For me the suggestion by Engerlost works.

Comment: Oh man. I forgot to include geometry library. Thanks for help anyway :)

Comment: @PiotrMhrokKuchar If my answer was useful beside the library, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x,y,countmarkers=0;
for(x=52.8;x<=54;x=x+0.15){
    for(y=12.6;y<=19;y=y+0.25) {

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, pole1)) {
             if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, pole2)){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: point,
                     map: map
                 });
                 countmarkers++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've edited the code. The correct suggestion from the comments was to use a `google.maps.LatLng` instead of a `LatLngLiteral` (which will not be accepted by `containsLocation`). This was the only issue.